# How to make blur-gradient interaction

Tags: css, gradient, blur

reference : http://www.agencekali.com

Hello, I wanna learn how to create this blur gradient color and movement in background with css. I assume this is made out of canvas given the sources. But I don't know what keywords I should look it up or how to move forward. Could you suggest articles that I can get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients

But keep in mind that you have been downvoted because this is a question easily found searching on Google, or any other search engine. 
Users are expected to make an effort and investigate by theirselves before posting questions to the community. 
In the process of investigating by yourself you are generally able to solve almost every question you'd have, specially in the beginning.

Good luck on your learning process! ^^

Comment: Yes sure. Thank you for your help. But creating gradient color is easy to find unlike making motion. I wondered the motion specifically and googled such as gradient interaction or motion, only to find nothing. That's why I posted this.